# Rules for Tirth Yarta

Tags: scripture, tirtha

What rules must one follow while on Tirth Yatra?
How must one start and end the yatra?
I came across these lines in Brahma Puran,

> If merely going to a tirtha is enough to purify, then the fish of the Ganga and the birds who roost in the temple towers would be instantly purified.

But, then some commentator added that these are for those who go lousily on tirth. Just as fishes & birds are unaware of being in tirtha. But, if someone follows all rules like Indriya nigraha & others while on tirth yatra, thus the yatra ultimately helps in realizing true self.
Thus, I wanted to all set of rules to be followed irrespective of any tirth yatra (like taking no gifts while in tirth, or doing Shaura karma (shave hairs) in every tirth, etc) from Sashtras.

Comment: some that i know - avoid staying in hotels (find mutts/ashrams/nivas). avoid eating in hotels (eat prasad from temples/ashrams, fruits, nuts). avoid sex (obvious). avoid frivolous talk about daily life. give donations. do upasana (japa, sandhya). listen to upanyasa/pravachan like itihasa, purana, especially sthala purana of that particular kshetra. recite shlokas.

Comment: There is also a ritual called Tirtha-sraddha. It is a special sraddha ceremony performed before leaving & after reaching a tirtha, which has completely fallen out of use in modern days.

Comment: @mar Thanks alot, yet I read in Yatra parva of Mahabharata that Vidurji went on Tirth Yatra for 36yrs & he carried nothing for in the way, he went barefoot to all tirth. But, today these things are bit difficult to follow. Thus what is your take on this?

Comment: @AnubrataBit this wasn't known to me. Thanks alot to point about this. But, is Tirth Shrada meant for all tirthas? Or is it confined for tirthas like Brahmakapala, Gaya or Haridwara?

Comment: Afaik, Visit to a tirtha is usually connected with any religious observance(owing to its spiritual ambience) ,like in the days of yore, SandhyaVandana / BrahmaYajna were done in tirta.Related to tharathi(cross)) , Tirtha provides a conducive ambience for one to cross their vicious tendencies , inorder to ascend to a higher spiritual plane.It is  known by hearsay, that Tirtha is a manifestation of a deity , unique it, Tirtha maahathmya in puranas may contain references. Perhaps, In Kali Yuga ,with  basic austerities as precursor ,a snana by chanting Lord's name followed by dhana  might suffice.

Comment: Rules(..day/time) may pertain  to region/customs/ ritual is done in tirta. Tirtha yatra is popular during pushkar(am) river festival once in 12 yrs

Comment: @Athrey Thanks to mark the spiritual significance & mentioning common rules. Thats true that every Tirtha has their own set of rules. Tho, I wished to know the general ones. Btw, can u please elaborate on the Pushkar river festive?

Comment: @Chamundadas ,In nutshell,Pushkar happens once in twelve yrs,during a unique planetary position. When jupiter  transits to a zodiac sign, corresponding to a sacred river,(for a period of 12 days, all devatas are said to reside in that river).Festival is held along 12 rivers.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushkaram

Comment: Could you please tell the numbering of the śloka you are referring to?